# Cropping image on left side in gallery view in android

Tags: android, ios, image

Am displaying images in gallery view from left side not from center using gallery.setSelection(1),but the first image which is on left side is gets cropped ,can anyone help me out on this

Below is the code

xml of gallery view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_checkout"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlImageBorder"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
             >

           <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/ivCheckbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:button="@drawable/icon_unchecked"
                android:checked="false" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivUserImage"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ivCheckbox"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar_big" />

        </RelativeLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvNameOfVisitor"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Child Name"
                 android:textColor="@color/kid_name"
                 android:textSize="23sp" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCheckOut"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten"
                 android:text="@string/checkOut"
                 android:textColor="@color/red"
                 android:textSize="20sp" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvEscortMsg"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Grade"
                 android:textColor="@color/dark_ash"
                 android:textSize="18sp" />
             <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDtAndTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Grade"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_ash"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/metingTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Grade"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_ash"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMetingTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Grade"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_ash"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
         </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

XML of main layout in which we are displaying gallery view:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="@color/header_border" android:layout_below="@+id/header_frame"/>
      <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlOfUnAuthorized"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llHeaderBelow"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_unauthorized"
            android:visibility="gone" >
         <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/tvUnAuthorized"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten"
                          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                          android:textColor="@color/dark_ash"
                          android:textSize="20sp"

                          />


         </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llHeaderBelow"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_frame"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llleft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
                android:clickable="true"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_back"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Welcome"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textColor="@color/profile_welcome_color"/>  

                      <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten"
                          android:text=" User Name"
                          android:textColor="@color/profile_welcome_name"
                          android:textSize="20sp"
                          android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTimeandDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="Date and Time"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textColor="@color/profile_date"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>




    <View   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/viewline"
        android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/header_border" android:layout_below="@+id/llHeaderBelow"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlbody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llHeaderBelow"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten" >

 <!--    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="My Kids"
                     android:textColor="@color/profile_name"
                          android:textSize="20sp"
                          android:textStyle="bold"  /> -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/customlayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_ban" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:textColor="#b94a48"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   >

                       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
            android:spacing="20dip"

            />

         <!--   <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/b" /> -->

                   <!--  <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true" /> -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />
    </RelativeLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlbtnFinish"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFinish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_finish"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
       <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me out ,so that it will be helpful for me

[image]